# Where to ask a question that is more about iOS custom care than iOS development

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

On Stack Overflow, I just asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805692/a-testflight-replacement-that-actually-gives-you-a-meaningful-error-message-when?noredirect=1#comment29445085_19805692. Basically it as to do with the distribution of an iOS app than developing it. I got a close request, I'm not sure which Stack Exchange site would be appropriate for it (assuming that it is indeed inappropriate or applicable to Stack Overflow)?

Answer (score 3):

There is an "Ask Different" SE for all Apple issues. It is located at https://apple.stackexchange.com/ and uses the StackOverflow model.